# How to get information from an external URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, playlist, video-player

I've recently been trying to get into HTML5 for a "quick" project. 
I wanted to make a video playlist where videos would play automatically when they end. There would be a couple of extra features too, like video selection etc by simple buttons.

I've got a link that contains a directory with all the URLs of the videos i'd like to be playable (listLink), but I can't find a way to access the content contained in that link.

So my question is, how do you get external URL information and pick out all the video urls in that HTML code?
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang ="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SU Video Player</title>
</head>

<Body>

<embed id="videoPlayer" 
src="https://dl.dropbox.com/s/bvv608uln671swf/s0e0.mp4?dl=0" loop="false" 
type="video/mp4" autostart="false" />

</body>

<script>

    // Get the videoPlayer
    var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoPlayer");

    // contains all the videos I'd like to be playable.
    // It's a directory, and in the HTML code of the link there are video links for every video.
    var listLink = "https://www.dropbox.com/sh/di8i7gob9b3mgle/AACOC5yDuBpttC2ZVYuxLJw5a?dl=0";

    document.link

    nextVideo = "https://dl.dropbox.com/sh/p23gpogpqwwuilq/AAAAthZF_4HKcaRt3gHIP9Mia/s1e1.mp4?dl=0";

    //videoPlayer.src = listLink("Video")[5];


    function NextVideo() {

        videoPlayer.src = nextVideo;
    }       

</script>
```

Comment: mostly, you'd use AJAX

Comment: Simply create an array with all video sources, and then using `onended` event, change the source of the video by using the `src` property.

Comment: Thanks guys, you've helped quite a bit. I ended up going with a local array of the links. That way I could easily make them objects, and add different attributes to them like title and description.

I almost got AJAX to work, but most browsers doesn't support cross-domain it seems like, so I ended up scratching that idea. I didn't want to make my first project too complicated. Thanks anyways!